# Can you change required field to not required for a custom metadata's page layout?

Tags: page-layout, custom-metadata

According to the following [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_req_managed_pkgs.htm&type=5), after you upload a Managed - Released package that contains a custom metadata type, you can’t:

- Add required fields to the custom metadata type.
- Set non-required fields to required.
- Delete custom fields that are in the uploaded version of the package. If you add a custom field after the upload, you can still delete it until you upload a new Managed - Released version.
- Delete public custom metadata records that are included in the package.
- Change a public custom metadata record or type in the package to protected. You can, however, change protected records and types to public.
- Change the manageability of any custom field in the package.

---

Now, none of these constraints pertain to the ability of changing required fields to not required. Yet, the page layouts do not change required fields to not required after such a change. Any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I realized so soon after that the field was set to required on the page layout itself. One can easily uncheck `required` by editing the field on the affected page layout.